# What grammar rule is applied in the following sentence: "The drilling platform **to be constructed** is determined based on the depth"

Tags: sentence-construction, tense

Could anybody help me out with the sentence I came across in my friend`s test:

The drilling platform **to be constructed** is determined based on the depth at which drilling must be carried out in a particular oil field.

What grammar rule is applied here when we use "to be constructed"?

I would personally choose the same answer but I can`t figure out how to explain it to my friend. the other options were 1)has been constructed; 2)is constructed

Comment: You said you would select  the same answer... but you didn't say what the options were.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the necessary details. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The drilling platform to be constructed is determined based on the depth at which drilling must be carried out in a particular oil field.

The phrase *to be constructed* is an adjectival infinitive and describes the noun *platform*.

An adjectival infinitive is a type of verbal, which is formed from a verb but may function as a noun, adverb, or adjective.

You can refer to this set of reference material from [Towson](https://webapps.towson.edu/ows/verbals.aspx).